# Python pickle is broken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, pickle, deque

I receive strange error when I try to pickle and unpikle object of custom class

```
from collections import deque
class Buffer(deque):
    def __init__(self, maxlen=cf.BUFFER_SIZE):
        super().__init__(maxlen=maxlen)
```

class contains some additional functionality, but even such simple implementation produce error

code to reproduce error:

```
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(Buffer()))
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-70ac6b3f6f8f> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(Buffer(), fix_imports=False))

TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Python version: 3.7.5 (default, Oct 25 2019, 15:51:11) [GCC 7.3.0]

Comment: When `pickle` tries to reconstitute your `Buffer` object, it's going to be passed all of the parameters that the underlying `deque` takes - which is both an iterable and the maxlen value.  You need to accept the `iterable` parameter as well, and pass it on in the `super().__init__()` call.  Think about it - how can you possibly restore a pickled `Buffer` if there's no way to specify any contents for it?